# Paypal Payments REST API Updating Payment to Add Item

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to add a second Item to a created payment via a PatchRequest but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
$patch = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
$patch->setOp('add');
$patch->setPath('/transactions/0/item_list/items/1');
$json = '
    {
        "description":"Testartikel",
        "price":"50.00",
        "currency":"EUR",
        "quantity":1
    }';
$data = json_decode($json);
$patch->setValue($data);
$patches[] = $patch;
$patchRequest = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
$patchRequest->setPatches($patches);
$payment->update($patchRequest, $apiContext);
```

So the request looks like this:

```
[{"op":"add","path":"/transactions/0/item_list/items/1","value":{"description":"Testartikel","price":"50.00","currency":"EUR","quantity":1}}]
```

I get this error:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"682441321797"}
```

I guess the path `/transactions/0/item_list/items/1` might be wrong but i couldn't figure out what would be the correct one. I already tried `/transactions/0/item_list` and `/transactions/0/item_list/items` with the same result.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Error Message.

The Problem were the missing square brackets round the JSON.

The right path is '/transactions/0/item_list/items'.

```
$json = '
[
  {
    "description":"Testartikel",
    "price":"50.00",
    "currency":"EUR",
    "quantity":1
  }
]';

$patchAdd = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
$patchAdd->setOp('add')
    ->setPath('/transactions/0/item_list/items')
    ->setValue(json_decode($json));

$patchRequest = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
$patchRequest->setPatches(array($patchAdd);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Ahhh so they expect an array as the value.. doh.. :)
Works like a charm now.. thanks a lot.

Comment: /transactions/0/item_list/items is correct. works with setOp ('replace') as well. Patching of transaction amount should not be forget...